# Certificate subject key Identifier length

Tags: security, openssl, certificate

I've got a certificate with the following Subject key Identifier:
34:4E:D9:3E:48:CB:17:18:63:57:A5:14:E1:DB:67:14:A7:CB:6A:F6

The x509 standard states that it should be 32bytes long, however it seems much longer to me.
How can I get the 32 byte SKI?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The x509 standard states that it should be 32bytes long

Where do you see that? There are two recommended ways for computing Subject Key Identifier, per [IETF RFC 3280, section 4.2.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.2.1.2):

> (1) The keyIdentifier is composed of the 160-bit SHA-1 hash of the
> value of the BIT STRING subjectPublicKey (excluding the tag,
> length, and number of unused bits).
>
> (2) The keyIdentifier is composed of a four bit type field with
> the value 0100 followed by the least significant 60 bits of the
> SHA-1 hash of the value of the BIT STRING subjectPublicKey
> (excluding the tag, length, and number of unused bit string bits).

So a 160-bit value, or a 64-bit value.  Neither of those are 32 bytes (or 32 bits).

RFC 5280 then adds "Other methods of generating unique numbers are also acceptable.".

[ITU-T X.509 (2016)](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.509-201610-S/en) doesn't provide any prescriptive guidance on creating the value... or how long it should be.